# Using NOT LIKE in db condition?

Tags: views, database

I don't see an example when looking at the api.  I'm setting up a query and would like to use `NOT LIKE` as opposed to `STARTS` since `START` does not seem to be supported.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Add this snippet to your query item:

```
$query->condition(X, Y, 'NOT LIKE');
```

where `X` and `Y` are two variables. You can also replace each of them with constants.

Comment: I tried this and it returned nada.  Going to retest.  Your answer was edited...  did I miss anything

Comment: @Baybook cast query to string and see. Maybe query is right or almost right now, and your problem is elsewhere? And if query looks totally wrong, post the code and query in question so we could see that answer is wrong or you made mistake using it :)